# How to add editor-style.css styling to wp_editor on front end for comments

Tags: comments, visual-editor, wp-editor, iframe

How can I apply my own css (to match `editor-style.css`) to `wp_editor` being used on the front end for comments?

Currently I'm using [code from here](http://www.revood.com/blog/adding-visual-editor-to-wordpress-comments-box-part-2/) to enable the visual editor for comments.

My actual code in `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'custom_comment_form_defaults' );
function custom_comment_form_defaults( $args ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $mce_plugins = 'inlinepopups, wordpress, wplink, wpdialogs';
    } else {
        $mce_plugins = 'fullscreen, wordpress';
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', create_function('', 'return "tinymce";') );
    ob_start();
    wp_editor( '', 'comment', array(
        'media_buttons' => false,
        'teeny' => true,
        'textarea_rows' => '7',
        'tinymce' => array( 'plugins' => $mce_plugins ),
        'editor_css' => '<style> p { font-family: Arial } </style>'
    ) );
    $args['comment_field'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $args;
}
```

As you can see in the code I'm passing a css style into `wp_editor` with the `editor_css` param, however it's getting rendered outside the `iframe` so it's having no affect.

You can see that style declaration and iframe [in the source here](http://www.wanderingjon.com/2012/04/22/kupu-maui-april-2012/).

Comment: I'm dealing with the same thing: I need to style the contents of the iframe generated by wp_editor(). There's supposed to be support for a parameter 'editor_css', which takes inline CSS and one would *think* apply it to the iframe HEAD or something, but NO - it addes it AFTER the iframe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually you can include the editor-style.css (or any other stylesheet), just pass a "content_css" value to tinymce that points to a css file:

```
wp_editor( 
    $content, 
    'editablecontent', 
    array( 
       'tinymce' => array( 
            'content_css' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/editor-styles.css' 
       ) 
    );
```

So the original posters code would look like:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'custom_comment_form_defaults' );
function custom_comment_form_defaults( $args ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $mce_plugins = 'inlinepopups, wordpress, wplink, wpdialogs';
    } else {
        $mce_plugins = 'fullscreen, wordpress';
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', create_function('', 'return "tinymce";') );
    ob_start();
    wp_editor( '', 'comment', array(
        'media_buttons' => false,
        'teeny' => true,
        'textarea_rows' => '7',
        'tinymce' => array( 
            'plugins' => $mce_plugins, 
            'content_css' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/editor-styles.css'
        )
    ) );
    $args['comment_field'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

you can't link to style sheet files here rather you can add inline css as follows:
In addition to this you can add a custom class, using which you can write css in your main css file.

```
$mystyle = '<style type="text/css">
           body{margin:0;padding:0}
           </style>';    

$settings = array(
    'editor_css' => $mystyle, 
    'editor_class' => 'myclass'
);
wp_editor($content, $editor_id, $settings );
```

Comment: Can $mystyle here not refer to an external stylesheet?  Something like:
`$mystyle = '<style type="text/css">' . file_get_contents(get_stylehseet_uri()) . '</style>';
`
That's totally untested code and might be ridiculous, more trying to illustrate an idea.  Also obviously, better to point at editor-style.css not the real theme style sheet.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the wp_editor() in a form that I'm building for guest posts. In order to get the background to style the way I needed it to, I added the following to my CSS:

```
.wp_themeSkin iframe{
    background: #FFF !important;
}
```

This will force it to override the other CSS that's being added to the form.

Comment: While that would style the iframe element itself, that doesn't style anything inside the iframe.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. I was just happy to get that transparent background to go away. I've tried using the !important tag on the interior elements to no avail. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

In WP 3.9.1 when you pass **tinymce** setting in front-end, it fails to load **inlinepopups** plugin for some reason.

So you can set editor styles through global variable and it won't break whatever logic they use for loading plugins.

```
$GLOBALS['editor_styles'] = array(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/editor_style.css');
```